# platform for long running http request?

Tags: api, request, external

I know this answer could be subjective, but I have the following problem that I can't find a way of how to handle it.

In my current system the user submit a request to an external system that I don't control. This request could take up to 30 minutes to get the response. Currently the max timeout that I can set when doing the API request is 120 seconds, so my system breaks when this request takes longer (I also don't want to have a request timeout that is that long).

I am wondering what platform are available or an AWS service that I can use to do something in the line of:

My system send the request to an external system, who sends me a response straight away like request in the queue, in the background this external system send the request to the third party (the ones that take long time) and once it finish and has the response send this response to a callback (in my current system)

[image]

I believe either Jitterbit or Mulesoft can do this, but from previous experience this platform has been way over my budget.

I just want to know what is the best or possible path(s) to tackle this type of problems

Comment: As written this looks like a request for us to *recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource*, which is [off topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).  But if you can share your current code that doesn't work then, with a [mcve], this would look a lot more on-topic.

Comment: BTW if you are using `HttpWebRequest` there may be two timeouts properties to set. See [Can't set HttpWebRequest timeout higher than 100 seconds when doing a POST?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7842736/3744182) and [How to set HttpWebRequest.Timeout for a large HTTP request in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36668219/3744182).

Comment: @dbc I was aware and affraid that it could be look as on off topic, the problem doesn't have anything to do with my code, the API request to this external system could take several minutes, it doesn't matter if it is executed using PHP, python, postman the external service simply could take up to 30 min to gather data for hence potential timeouts. I am not asking for a book or tutorial, just what systems are out there that could handle doing an API with long time to get the response

Comment: Your 3rd party API should be able to be designed in such a way that when you first call it, it just responds immediately providing you a technical acknowledgment saying that it has received a request. When it has completed the work, it can either call your API endpoint to pass the response, OR it could provide you a job id as a response in the first call and you use this job id to keep checking status of whether the job has been completed in the target system. When completed, you use another target API to pull the response. Basically, you have to decouple first request from the second.

Comment: @Rohan yes you will expect that they will develop their app to handle that by either sending back a jobID for you to request later or by sending the response to a callback URL when they cant warrantythat the respond will happen in a matter of a few seconds, but unfortunately that is not the case here, and as that is a third party is not much on my end I can do